# Page load speed Magento 1.9

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, magento-1.9

My Store created in Magento1.9. My Problem is if I put .htaccess file with this code.

```
    DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value memory_limit 512M
php_value max_execution_time 18000
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
php_flag session.auto_start off
php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off
php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
SSLOptions StdEnvVars
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
</IfModule>
 AddDefaultCharset Off
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

for index.php remove from URL then Site pages load very slow and If I Removed this .htaccess then on site all pages open very fast.

So How I can handle this ??

I want to remove index.php from URL and page load very fast.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The page loads very slow because

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value memory_limit 512M
php_value max_execution_time 18000
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
php_flag session.auto_start off
php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off
php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off
</IfModule>
```

All the above mentioned details are overriding the php.ini file configuration. So it means, first the php.ini file loads and on top of that this .htaccess will load. So only it is taking more time to loads a page.

The page loads very fast when you remove this file, because it will take the general configuration which is already mentioned in the `php.ini` file. So only it will load fast when you remove this configurations.

If you want only index.php to get removed from the URL, then the below code is responsible for that.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Just try to make the above changes in the default .htaccess file as per the above code.

Comment: Thanks for explaining I tried this but same thing happens Page load very slow